# is_multisite(); Support for Wordpress 3.0

Tags: php, wordpress

Looking for a variable to use to differentiate between sites in a Wordpress 3.0 Multisite installation. I saw the function "is_multisite();" in some blogs, but not sure if its supported yet. I have one theme I'd like to use on all the Network's sites, but need a way to use conditions between them.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The wordpress install itself, I believe, uses it; so I imagine its supported. However, alot of people have reported problems with the install calling `is_multisite()` (http://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+is_multisite), but I haven't been able to find *any* documentation for it.

Comment: yea, I found it in the glossary, but its doesn't have any documentation on it yet, which is why I assumed it might be supported in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This [article dicusses](http://frumph.net/wordpress/wordpress-plugin-theme-check-for-multisitewpmu/) a few different techniques for determining if the site is in a Multisite installation.  Below is a cleaned up version of their custom function:

```
function yourtheme_is_multsite() {
    global $wpmu_version;
    if (function_exists('is_multisite'))
        return is_multisite();
    return !empty($wpmu_version));
}
```

Comment: that seems to be determining whether its a multisite or a MU site. I already know its a Multisite. I was thinking I might be able to use the get_bloginfo('url') are a variable but it didn't work.

ie.

if get_bloginfo('url') == site.com else if etc...

Answer (score 0):

`$current_blog->blog_id` or `->path` might be what you're looking for? They differentiate sites within the same network (albeit not in a very helpful way).

http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Global_Variables